# Where can I find a feature list for venia storefront for magento PWA studio?

Tags: magento2.3.4

Can Anybody help me to find out all good features of venia storefront and bugs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Features of PWA(Venia storefront) are fast, responsive, Cross-browser compatible, Offline Mode, Mobile “Install”, Shareable content. Please refer the [official documentation](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/technologies/overview/#what-is-a-progressive-web-app) for more info.

For understanding venia project structure refer [this](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/project-structure/).

Demo URL to test available functionalities: https://venia.magento.com/

For open bug list check [here](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/issues)